# How to extract a specific cluster after filtering a point cloud?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I'm working with the point cloud library, and I am extracting the points of the first cluster after filtering a point cloud and segmenting with Euclidean Cluster Extraction. The following code is what I think might work to extract the points of the cluster:

```cpp
std::vector<pcl::PointIndices> cluster_indices;
typename pcl::search::KdTree<PointT>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<PointT>);
tree->setInputCloud(out_cloud);
pcl::EuclideanClusterExtraction<PointT> ec;
ec.setClusterTolerance(2 * 0.06);
ec.setMinClusterSize(50);
ec.setMaxClusterSize(1200);
ec.setSearchMethod(tree);
ec.setInputCloud(filtered_cloud);
ec.extract(cluster_indices);
int j = cluster_indices.size();
tam_cluster = cluster_indices[0].indices.size();
int ind_tmp;

for (int n=0; n<tam_cluster; n++){
    ind_tmp=cluster_indices[0].indices[n];
    first_clust->points.push_back (filtered_cloud->points[ind_tmp]); 
}
std::cout << " ** Number of points of first cluster : " <<  first_clust->size() <<std::endl;
```

So, I don't know why but sometimes I get a cluster with more than 1200 points. I think it might be due to the `pcl` implementation in extracting clusters.

Is this code correct?

Comment: What is the `typename` for?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to change that line of the code so it is just  : pcl::search::KdTree<PointT>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<PointT>);
   tree->setInputCloud(filtered_cloud);

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue, once u go though this sample code this might be useful
[GitHub Link for Cluster Extraction](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/examples/segmentation/example_extract_clusters_normals.cpp)

Try varying the values of these parameters SetRadiusSearch, tolerance, eps_angle, min_cluster_size and u will get the total clusters count and all the cluster data will be saved to separate pcd files.

hope this helps you.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)